# How to use C++ to generate super large independent and uniform distribution random numbers for cryptographic uses

Tags: c++, cryptography, biginteger

For example, linear congruence might not be secure enough when generating random numbers when it is used in cryptography even though it is much easier to implement. Are there existing methods to help us generate super large (e.g., 1024-bit) random numbers or are there possible ways to generate that large numbers uniformly and independently?

Comment: Try here: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers#Software

Comment: [Cryptographically-secure pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically-secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)

Comment: There are no cryptographically-secure random number generators in the standard library. Anything cryptography-related should also not be implemented manually, because of the high risk of making serious mistakes, especially without expertise (consider for example timing side channel attacks). So you have to use a library specifically offering that, as for example linked above. Questions for library recommendations are however off-topic, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about cryptographiy then pseduorandom number gnerators just don't cut it. Read 1024 bit from /dev/random on unix or whatever is equivalent on windows.